# Arduino function variable value changes between function calls

Tags: c, arduino

I have three functions, each calls the next and passes some values. Strangely, in second function where I make multiple calls to third function, one of the values changes between the calls. And this variable is for sure local. Am I missing Something?

```
void functionA(...){
  //Something...
  int i=1,j=1,k=2;
  functionB(i,j,k);
}

void functionB(int i,int j,int k){
  String X="";
  Serial.print(i);//Gives 1
  if(j==1)
    X="hello world";
  functionC(i,j,k,X);//Call 1 to functionC
  Serial.print(i);//Gives 0 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  if(j==2)
    X="hello world2";
  functionC(i,j,k,X);//Call 2 to functionC
}

void functionC(int i, int j, int k, String X){

   if(i) 
     //Do something
   else 
     //Do somethingelse

}
```

My experiments

```
void functionC(int i, int j, int k, String X){
       //Print i here. No difference with the result.
       if(i) 
         //Do something
       else 
         //Do somethingelse
       //But if I Print i here again, then it is working. As in, "i" does not change anymore. between each call to functionC
    }
```

Comment: You only have 1 call to functionC in your example as it is.

Comment: Sorry,. updated question/ code

Comment: Please, print again `i` after the second call

Comment: How did this even compile? In `functionB` you have X only local for `if`. It can't be passed to the `functionC` call as it's outside of scope.

Comment: @KIIV wow I just noticed that!  That's a really good question... this definitely shouldn't compile as is.

Comment: Your chances of getting a useful answer would be greatly improved if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry the code was very large, so I wanted to show the structure. My mistake. I have updated the code. Also, some findings after playing around.

Comment: @aVC Let me check if I well understood your test: does the `functionC()` procedure print both the times a value for `i` that is 1 as first print?

Comment: No, it prints 1 first, and next time it prints 0.

Comment: As a sanity check, it might be better to put the first Serial.print(i) right before the first call to `functionC`, and then you can be sure that something in `functionC` must be changing that value.  Are you sure you're not doing anything with addresses in `functionC`?  I think we would need to see more of that functions' code because we can really only offer guesses as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're passing some pointers around or functionC is doing some funky stuff with memory.  Other than those two options, there's no real reason I can see why a value in a variable would simply change like in your example.

Comment: I agree, it is really difficult to help you if you do not provide us the code of the `functionC()` procedure

Comment: @acornagl Sorry the code was very large, so I wanted to show the structure. My mistake. I have updated the code. Also, some findings after playing around.

Comment: @aVC, don't worry we are here to try to help you and I am pretty sure that you tried to give us all the necessary information to receive an answer ;)